# What if the title sufficiently explains the entire question?

Tags: discussion, questions

Here's [an example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73/how-can-i-set-the-processor-affinity-of-a-process-on-linux). Do you just repeat the question, like she did? What value does that add?

Answer (score 2):

It might always be nice to see if the OP put some thought into the matter beforehand.

Also, when skimming the "new questions" list, I'd like to know what a question is about from the title; usually (as for your example) I react quicker if I see "processor affinity" or some short-hand in the title. Sure, there's tags and all, but personally I like short titles and detailed questions.

That also suppressed the typical *"...and what have you tried, yet?"* comments. At least at SO I see those **a lot.**