# Asking Questions in the Title

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should “Title Says It All” questions be edited or closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119410/should-title-says-it-all-questions-be-edited-or-closed)

I've noticed a growing trend on StackExchange where some people actually write out the question in the title field and don't have much meat in the actual body. So, for example, something like this:

**Title:** Why are both OnCreate and OnResume called when an Android app is launched?

**Body:** Could someone help me, please?

Are these kinds of questions acceptable?

Comment: Realted: [What if the title sufficiently explains the entire question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76662/what-if-the-title-sufficiently-explains-the-entire-question) [What should I write in the question body if the title already explains everything?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145019/what-should-i-write-in-the-question-body-if-the-title-already-explains-everythin)

Answer (score 6):

I see sometimes such questions.

I wouldn't say this is unacceptable on a rule, but **all of the ones I saw** badly ended because they weren't precise enough.

OP sometimes is irate against the rule forcing him to put some content but the fact is : almost all those questions are bad. When you think about the question you ask, the type of answer you need, why you ask such a question, then you **always** have details to add.

Or you should just ask Google.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts. I wondered if asking questions in the title was indeed tied to the poor quality of the post. I'm too new to make that link yet.

Comment: Asking a question in the title is fine. What's not fine is not detailing the question in the body.

Answer (score 2):

I always remove  `Could someone help me, please?` and `Thanks` as fluff so in this case the question body would be completely empty!? Usually if you can asked a question in the title alone I would say the top Google results would give you the answer.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your thoughts.